# C# - Anonymous delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

Like Anonymous Methods ,the delegates i am declaring down using "delegate" keyword are anonymous delegates?

```
namespace Test
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DelegateTest tst = new DelegateTest();
            tst.Chaining();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    class DelegateTest
    {
        public event MyDelegate del;

        public void Chaining()
        {
            del += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); };
            del += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Good Things"); };
            del += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Wonderful World"); };
            del();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your delegate collection in the example points to a number of anonymous methods. A delegate is "just a method pointer". It doesn't matter if it points to a real method or an anonymous method.

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx

Comment: link is dead, but propably lead to something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/delegates-with-named-vs-anonymous-methods

Answer (score 25):

There's no such thing as an "anonymous delegate" (or rather, that's not a recognised term in the C# specification, or any other .NET-related specification I'm aware of).

There are anonymous functions which include anonymous methods and lambda expressions.

Your code shows plain old anonymous methods - although they *are* using the one feature lambda expressions don't have: the ability to not express the parameters at all when you don't care about them.

Comment: Umm. can you clarify on this.. we usually see "Anonymous Delegates" term used every where also there is term "Anonymous Methods" as used in MSDN, so are we wrong in saying former or both are correct..

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: "Anonymous methods" is correct. "Anonymous delegates" is incorrect. You say that you "usually see [it] every where" - could you cite specific places?

Comment: Not in any official document but usual terminology used by Netizens. Like... SO itself.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=anonymous+delegate .... so looks like we have gone in habit of using wrong term.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: Yup, there's plenty of terminology which is used incorrectly :(

Comment: Thanx for clarification...(looks like i got something to write about on my next blog post)... :)

Comment: Thanks. I guess anonymous methods are called "anonymous delegates" because `delegate` is used in their definition. When I saw the definitions of anonymous methods, I have mistaken them as definitions of delegate types because of the appearance of `delegate`. Do `delegate`'s used in the definition of an anonymous method and in the definition of a delegate type the same? C# in a Nutshell says that `delegate` used in the former case is a keyword, so is `delegate` used in the latter case also the same keyword?

Comment: @Tim: They're both referring to the same concept, yes - an anonymous method is always converted to a delegate type.

Comment: By "an anonymous method is always converted to a delegate type", Do you mean C# compiler always converts  an anonymous method into a instance of a delegate type?

Comment: @Tim Yes. Without the conversion, the expression has no type in itself.

Comment: Thanks. I bumped into ["anonymous delegate" in a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697746/does-c-sharp-have-unlimited-extent-for-anonymous-methods). So as the book says,  anonymous methods have unlimited extent/ Why is that? Do lambda expressions also have unlimited extent? Does "extent" mean "lifetime", correct?

Comment: @Tim: I wouldn't like to guess what the author means by "unlimited extent" to be honest. I could imagine it referring to: 1) The number of statements in the anonymous method; 2) The lifetime of the delegate being created; 3) The amount of work that the anonymous method performs (how long it runs for). I'd certainly recommend against making personal criticism of others who don't know how this non-standard term is being used by the author of the book.

Comment: It does exists and it's explained as oficial .NET specification by Microsoft, just check the validated answer to this question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/delegates-with-named-vs-anonymous-methods

Comment: @Windgate: The term "anonymous delegate" does not appear anywhere in that page. The page uses "anonymous method" which *does* exist. If you believe ther'es any reference to "anonymous delegate" in that page, please could you cite the full sentence?

Comment: The title says "Delegates with Named vs. Anonymous Methods", if you think that "delegates with anonymous methods" is not the same as "anonymous delegates" or generate any doubts then ok, the candy is for you, I understood the question perfectly and did not see it necessary to generate a reply just to correct the author

Comment: @Windgate: This question appears to be specifically about terminology, trying to distinguish between "anonymous methods" and "anonymous delegates". The latter simply is *not* a term in C#, and I believe the OP benefits from knowing that, given that they were asking a terminology question...

Answer (score 4):

That's correct, you have assigned a number of anonymous methods to an event.

If you're using a newer version of c#, you can also do something similar with lambdas.  for example:

```
class DelegateTest
{
    public event Action del;

    public void Chaining()
    {
        del += () => Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        del += () => Console.WriteLine("Good Things");
        del += () => Console.WriteLine("Wonderful World");
        del();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are anonymous delegates (or, more specific, [delegates calling an anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Anonymous delegates cannot be referred to directly by name, so using the `delegate(){}` syntax means they are anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

Your delegate is not anonymous. It's called MyDelegate. 
Delegate in CLR is a class that derives from System.MulticastDelegate and in your case it's called MyDelegate. 
You cannot directly derive from MulticastDelegate, C# compiler will stop you.

In your code when you assign delegates to del, the type/name of the delegate is inferred by compiler because you declared del as event of type MyDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

They are delegates to anonymous methods. This is one way to make anonymous methods, which was available since .NET 2.0. With .NET 3.0 you can also use lambda expressions which are simpler to write (but compile to the same code). I suppose that's what you meant with "anonymouse methods". But really, they are one and the same thing.

Comment: Lambda expressions and anonymous methods in lambda syntax are not really the same. Your statement is true if you use the lambda syntax with curly braces: (x) => {y();}