# C#; making a new delegate without declaring the method separately?

Tags: c#, syntax, delegates

I'm able to compile code that includes this:

```
OperationDelegate myOpDelegate;
static OperatorDefinition[] definitions ={
                new OperatorDefinition("+",2,3,true, new OperationDelegate(OperationAdd)),
            };
delegate double OperationDelegate(double[] args);
static double OperationAdd(double[] args)
            {
                return args[0] + args[1];
            }
```

but I think my code would look cleaner if I could do something more like this:

```
OperationDelegate myOpDelegate;
static OperatorDefinition[] definitions ={new OperatorDefinition("+",2,3,true, new OperationDelegate({return args[0]+args[1]}))};
delegate double OperationDelegate(double[] args);
```

because I want to define everything about each OperatorDefinition in a single place, rather than defining the functions separately. Is there some way to do this in C#?

(any other criticism about my code would be welcome, too)

Comment: try lambda expressions... they are neat , clean, and concise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into anonymous methods...  for example this: [C# - Anonymous delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748719/c-anonymous-delegate)

Comment: Thanks; just knowing the term "anonymous delegate" let me find plenty of examples very quickly.

Comment: "I don't know what I don't know" ~ I `hate` when I run into that one. Glad you found what you needed @divider

Answer (score 6):

You can use Lambda expressions as from .Net 3.5:

```
 static OperatorDefinition[] definitions ={
    new OperatorDefinition("+",2,3,true, 
        args => args[0] + args[1])
    };
```

In your `OperatorDefinition` constructor, last parameter should be of type `Func<double[],double>`

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: I ended up with "new OperatorDefinition("*",2,4,true, delegate(double[] args){return args[0]*args[1];}"; is this any worse than yours?

Comment: It's a matter of taste - I think Lambda is shorter and more readable

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the link to MSDN got truncated.